# free dynamically allocated memory

Tags: c, free

```
int i;
char *s = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*10);
for(i = 0; i <= 4; ++i)
    s[i] = 'a';
s[5] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", s);
free(s).
```

Will the above code have memory leak problem? How does the function
"free" know how many memory need to be freed?

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is redundant here.

Comment: Redundant maybe, but good practice nonetheless.

Comment: How is `sizeof(char)` ever good practice?  It's `1`, plain & simple.  If you want to change the type later, it would be better to use `sizeof *s` anyway.

Comment: That's a fair point. It's good to get into the habit of making it *crystal clear* what you're trying to do; I've been bitten by this type of code before when people just put the *actual number* of bytes they needed instead of showign that they actually meant to allocate `n` objects of type `t`. But you are right that the better and more "bulletproof" way would be to just use `sizeof(*s)` instead of `sizeof(some_type)`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no memory leak in your code.  As to your second question, when you call `malloc`, more happens than just returning memory to you.  The C library reserves some space to put its own headers and bookkeeping information so that when you call `free` it can do the right thing.

Some editorial notes about your code:

- you don't need to cast the return value of `malloc()` in a C program.  Conversions between `void *` (which `malloc()` returns) and other pointer types are implicit in C.
- `sizeof(char)` is `1`, why bother writing it out?
- your loop writes three characters into `s`, and then your program skips a character (`s[4]`) before adding the `\0`.  That's a bit weird.  Did you mean to use `i <= 4` in your loop, or maybe `s[4] = '\0'` after it?
- you have a `.` rather than a `;` after your `free()` call.  I guess that's just a typo here, rather than in your program, since it won't compile that way, though.

Comment: Excellent and very thorough answer.

Answer (score 2):

It will not leak. The library knows how much to free because it internally keeps track of the allocated size of every block. The exact way it does that is an implementation detail that may change from `malloc` to `malloc` even from release to release and you should not be concerned with it.

Comment: You might need to be concerned with it if you're writing the implementation!

Comment: That's certainly true - but *if* you are, you wouldn't be asking this type of question on StackOverflow ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, you free s at the end and you don't use more than s.  I'd say you're ok.